# Plotting a stacked and grouped barchart in r

Tags: r, bar-chart, binary-data, categorical-data

I'm currently trying to plot some data in R, and not really succeeding. My data looks like this:

My data is stored in a data frame called "Head":
My response variable is a factor (called "colour") with only two levels ("black" and "white")
My first (and main) explanatory variable is a factor (called "Year" with two levels ("Year 1996" and "Year 2019").
My secondary explanatory variable is a factor (called "DateClass") with three levels ("A", "B" and "C").
So the dataset looks something like this:

Colour       Year        DateClass

Black        1996            A

Black        2019            B

White        1996            A

Black        1996            C

White        2019            B

White        1996            B

...etc

I want to plot "head colour" as a proportion of white/black vs "Year" and "DateClass". I had thought of a grouped barchart and stacking Black and White, but I don't know how to do it. Any suggestions? Would you plot the stacks of "colour" as percent or as total counts?

Thank you for your answers, best regards

Comment: have you tried anything? https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/stacked-barplot.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grouped and stacked barplot using base R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997632/grouped-and-stacked-barplot-using-base-r)

Comment: You could start with 'table()' first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

**DATA**:

```
df <- data.frame(Colour = c("Black", "Black", "White", "Black", "White", "White"),
                 Year = c(1996, 2019, 1996, 1996,2019, 1996),
                 DateClass = c("A", "B", "A", "C", "B", "B"))
```

**EDITED SOLUTION**:

First, aggregate the data to obtain the proportions of `Colour`by `DateClass` in **subsets** of `df` by `Year==2019` and, respectively, `Year==2019`; store the results in `df1996` and `df2019`:

```
df1996 <- aggregate(
  x = df$DateClass[df$Year==1996],
  by = list(df$Colour[df$Year==1996]),
  function(x) prop.table(table(x)))

df2019 <- aggregate(
  x = df$DateClass[df$Year==2019],
  by = list(df$Colour[df$Year==2019]),
  function(x) prop.table(table(x)))
```

Now plot the two dataframes side by side using a two-panel layout:

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
barplot(df1996[,-1], cex.names = 0.8, col = c("blue","red"),
        main = "Black/White by DateClass in 1996", cex.main = 0.8,
        xlab = "1996", ylab = "Proportions")

barplot(df2019[,-1], cex.names = 0.8, col = c("blue","red"),
        main = "Black/White by DateClass in 2019", cex.main = 0.8,
        xlab = "2019", ylab = "Proportions")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the input. Unfortunately, this isn't entirely what I was looking for. I was trying to have proportion of black/white for the three date classes in both years.
Thanks a lot though :)

Comment: Hi, I've edited the solution. Do let me know if this is what you had in mind.

Comment: Oh yes! This is what I was looking for! Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Glad to hear! DO feel free to accept the answer by clicking the green tick mark in the left upper corner. Thank you.