# I have two individual bars, I want to put these bars side by side in a barchart

Tags: r, plot

I have 5 nominal variables, let's call them A,B,C,D,E.

All of these variables have a continuous number associated.

3 of these variables (A,B,C) fall into "Group 1" category, while (D,E) fall into "Group 2" category.

I want to create a `barplot()` with 2 bars next to each other, the first bar should be group1, with the height as the average of the 3 values, however, I also want this to be coloured so that the bar is split into 3 different colours, showing a comparison between each bars impact on the graph.

I've attached what the group 1 bar should look like, and then what the group 2 bar should look like, I just want these to be side by side one another.

[image]

[image]

I've tried using `rbind()`, but I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing. Every time I do it, I end up getting a `barplot()` with 3 bars instead of 2.

Essentially, I'm looking for a way to put two individual bars beside each other.

Here is the code for my two bar plots:

```
# Group 1: 
barplot(as.matrix(group1), col=c("Red","Green","Blue"), beside=FALSE, legend=c("A","B","C"))
# Group 2: 
barplot(as.matrix(group2),col=c("Yellow","Pink"),beside=FALSE,legend=c("D","E"))
```

I should note, the group1 and group2 variables are just c()'d values of a,b,c and d,e

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then I would calculate the proportion of impact that each group (A, B, C, D, or E) has on the average before plotting, and then using these values to make the graph. The following would be a way of implementing it by using functions from the `tidyverse` library.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame("Letter" = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), "value" = c(50,40,35,78,88), "group" = as.character(c(1,1,1,2,2)))

df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate("mean_group" = mean(value), "prop_sum" = value/sum(value)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate("prop_of_mean" = mean_group*prop_sum) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = prop_of_mean, x = group, fill = Letter)) +
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")
```

[image: Stacked barchart]

It could of course also be done with the `barplot()`, if you prefer it.

Answer (score -1):

Finally, in `base R` it is not as trivial as one would think. Using `par(mfrow = c(1,2)` helps to solve, any other solution like presented here [Grouped and stacked barplot using base R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997632/grouped-and-stacked-barplot-using-base-r) is somehow cumbersome:

```
dev.off()
par(mfrow = c(1,2))

# Create matrices
group1 <- matrix(c(10, 45, 6), nrow=3, ncol=1, byrow=TRUE, dimnames=list(c("A", "B", "C"), c("group1")))
group2 <- matrix(c(53, 3), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(c("D", "E"), c("group2")))

# stacked barplot
# Group 1:
barplot(as.matrix(group1), col=c("Red","Green","Blue"), beside=FALSE, legend=c("A","B","C"))
# Group 2:
barplot(as.matrix(group2),col=c("Yellow","Pink"),beside=FALSE,legend=c("D","E"), yaxt='n')
```

[image]